# Automapper in asp.netcore for request and resposes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can we use AutoMapper in asp.netcore to map the request and responses?

I found out the usage of automapper in server response

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>());

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
OrderDto dto = mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);

var config = AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

is it possible that we map the request with automapper? I didn't find any reference to that

please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to map in reverse order of the example you posted above?

Comment: is that the correct way to map the request? how can we do that?

Comment: here is a nice tutorial on how to use automapper [https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/](https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/) 
you can use it for mapping any type A to Type B